# ping works but iperf3 doesn't show any traffic for TCP

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, iperf

machine `A` has IP (`eth0: 192.168.1.1`, `eth1: 10.10.xxx.yy`)
machine `B` has IP (`eth0: 192.168.1.2`)

`A` and `B` are connected through RJ5 on eth0, both sides. 
`ping` works fine on both side, but when running `iperf3` on a client-server mode, it doesn't show any traffic when using TCP.

`B` started with the following command :

```
iperf3 -s
```

`A` with this :

```
iperf3 -B192.168.1.1 -c192.168.1.2 -n 10G -b1000M
```

but no connection. It timesout with 'unable to connect to server'. This happens both for TCP and UDP. `iperf` works for UDP, but for TCP it doesn't work with `-b` option. I need `iperf3` as I want to test bandwidth with TCP. I am using `iperf3-3.*.el6.rpm` from epel. Is it broken ?

Comment: you are running as root, right?

Comment: yes, root for both machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have packet filtering enabled on machine B? What is the output of `iptables -L -v` on machine B? What is the output of `nmap 192.168.1.2` on machine A?

Comment: great point. That was silly of me for not checking iptables. That's what solves this. Thanks... I guess now you will have a bunch of rep.

Comment: how did this solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For me I tried a different port and it worked, since I didn't want to mess with the iptables rules that were already on the nodes.

```
# iperf3 -s -p 8000

# iperf3 -c 10.0.0.2 -p 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add TCP port 5201 to the firewall exception on machine B.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5201/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```